# How to add the callback URL to Twilio SMS sending code?

Tags: php, twilio

I'm using the official PHP Twilio library code for sending and receiving call. I can send an SMS using the example code below:

```
<?php
require('twilio/Twilio.php');

$sid = "AC************";
$token = "2************";

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$message = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
  '+1905xxxxxxx', // From a valid Twilio number
  '+278xxxxxxxx', // Text this number
  "Hello, test SMS message number 001!"
);
?>
```

Now I wan to add the callback URL to the above code. It can do it, but I don't know how to add the array for the $params.

```
function create($from, $to, $body, array $params = array()) {
    return parent::_create(array(
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Body' => $body
    ) + $params);
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try as below

```
function create($from, $to, $body, array $params = array()) {
    return parent::_create(array(
        'From' => $from,
        'To' => $to,
        'Body' => $body
    ) + array('StatusCallback'=>'http://yourdomain.com/yoururl.php'));
}
```

**OR**

```
$message = $client->account->sms_messages->create(
  '+1905xxxxxxx', // From a valid Twilio number
  '+278xxxxxxxx', // Text this number
  "Hello, test SMS message number 001!",
   array('StatusCallback'=>'http://yourdomain.com/yoururl.php')
);
```

You can learn more about how to use `StatusCallback` when sending sms [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages#post-parameters-optional).

Comment: What if I want to specify TwiML application instead of status callback url?

Comment: @Victor I know this question is almost three years old, but for the TwiML code look at [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/twiml/message) `$response = new Twiml();
$response->message('Store Location: 123 Easy St.',
    ['action' => '/SmsHandler.php', 'method' => 'POST']);` Replace "/SmsHandler.php" with your CallBack URL.