# Twilio - twilio/sdk PHP Status Callback for messages

Tags: php, twilio

I am attempting to set a StatusCallback on outgoing SMS messages using `twilio/sdk` - see https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php

The problem I'm running into is that it would appear that the StatusCallback option should be included in an array after the Body, like so:

```
$this->twilio->account->messages->sendMessage(
                    "+{$this->client->number}",
                    "+{$phone->number}",
                    $outgoing,
                    array('StatusCallback' => 'http://foo.bar/status')
                );
```

.. but Twilio now supports MMS messaging and seems to be considering this a reference to media. What am I missing? How can I use the Status Callback with this helper library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Check out this post and answer which seem to fit your question:

[How to add the callback URL to Twilio SMS sending code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212047/how-to-add-the-callback-url-to-twilio-sms-sending-code)

Specifically notice that when building the array in the fourth parameter you can actually specify key/value pairs, where the key is the parameter you're trying to send Twilio.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! One more question - will Twilio send data to this endpoint with every phase? For example, will it send when it is Sent and then Delivered? So far it only seems to be capturing when it was Sent.

Comment: Yes, you should get two status callbacks if the status changes twice.  Keep in mind that we don't always get a delivery receipt back from the carrier.  In those cases the status will remain 'Sent' so you would only get a single request to your status callback URL.