# How to handle twilio outgoing call if no answer

Tags: php, wordpress, twilio

I am implementing twilio outgoing call with wordpress woocommerce. As soon as the order is placed the site owner will receive a call. However i couldn't find a way to handle if the person didn't answer the call for some reason. The documentation is going above my head.

What i want is to make twilio recall if the call isn't answered. Or i am open to suggestion how else would be the good way to handle. Please note that i have not created any application at Twilio yet. Just using the PHP SDK as the account id and token is provided by default.

here is the code

```
function send_order_Call($order_id) {
    try {
        $file = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "order.xml";
        $twiML = simplexml_load_file($file);
        $twiML->Say = "Hello, You have received a new order. The order id is {$order_id}. Kindly check you fax for details";
        file_put_contents($file, $twiML->asXML());
        require_once 'Twilio.php';
        //Initializing Twilio Rest
        $sid = "ACcbd06f8e73asdfsdaf1"; 
        $token = "32ccf4bdcasdfsafc"; 
        $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

        $call = $client->account->calls->create("+12asfsaf", "+1ssd8777asfsf7", site_url()."/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-twilio/order.xml", array());
//        echo $call->sid;
    } catch (Exception $e){
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        die($error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR; You need to set the statusCallBack parameter for the options array.

Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24482140/1751451